# Height using div to get a empty white space, how do i do that?

Tags: html, css

Below is the css code:

```
.2line_break{width: 960px;height: 2px;}
```

Am trying to get a 2px height line break for the website using DIV, but it is not working. There is more height gap then 2px height.

Also tried:

```
.2line_break{width: 960px;min-height: 2px;}
```

I tried even with the tables, still not working. Any solution for this one?

Comment: Have you searched for margins and paddings? Please provide some code so we can help you

Comment: hi, yes tried also with margins and paddings, nothing happens.

"in the html file, i have: <div class="line_break"></div>" "style.css file: .line_break{width: 960px;height: 2px; background: white;}"

Answer (score 0):

The classname can't start with integer, when I rename your class name, it works.

```
<div>abc</div>
<div class="line_break"></div>
<div>abc</div>

div {background: green;}
.line_break{width: 960px;height: 2px; background: red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae1zfx6y/

But for making a gap you don't need to add extra element into your HTML, use margin.

```
<div class="margin_between">abc</div>
<div class="margin_between">abc</div>
<div class="margin_between">abc</div> 

div.margin_between {background: green;}
div.margin_between + div.margin_between {margin-top: 2px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae1zfx6y/2/

Comment: Hi, removed the integer, still not working.

"in the html file, i have: <div class="line_break"></div>"

"style.css file: .line_break{width: 960px;height: 2px; background: white;}"

Even though i try the div+div, it applies to the overall website, which is built using div's

Comment: @Sharath-designer: what about my two fiddle links? In both there is 2px gap (in the first one it's red between green boxes, in the second one it's white (transparent) between two green boxes). The second way using `margin` is the correct one (no need to add another elements into your HTML).

Comment: @Sharath-designer: See my updated answer, it was just a example code, added a classname to html and css (`margin_between`). So just add any classname to boxes you want to make a gap between. If you add a link to your page, we can find a context without need to add this classname.

Comment: The line with 2px green background shows up. 

But there is still some gap below it, which is 20px in height, unable to figure out where that is showing up from.

Comment: Without link to your site I can't tell you what makes this 20px gap. I can make a tip only, 20px is default margin on body. Why you can't post a link to your page? Without that I can't help you more :-(